# Need to convert MySQL group by query to oracle

Tags: mysql, sql, oracle11g

How can I convert this query to Oracle group By. I am facing the issue when migrating the application from MySQL to Oracle database.

```
SELECT j.id                   AS j__id
,      j.processing_office_id AS j__processing_office_id
,      j.lga_id               AS j__lga_id
,      j.created_at           AS j__created_at
,      j.updated_at           AS j__updated_at
,      j.created_by           AS j__created_by
,      j.updated_by           AS j__updated_by
,      j.deleted_at           AS j__deleted_at
,      t.name                 AS t__0
,      t3.id                  AS t3__1
,      t3.name                AS t3__2 
FROM   join_processing_office_state_lga j 
LEFT 
JOIN   tbl_lga t 
ON     j.lga_id = t.id 
AND    t.deleted_at IS NULL
AND    t.active_flag = 'Y'
LEFT 
JOIN   tbl_procesing_office t2
ON     j.processing_office_id = t2.id
LEFT 
JOIN   tbl_state t3 
ON     t.state_id = t3.id
AND    t3.deleted_at IS NULL
AND    t3.active_flag = 'Y'
WHERE  t2.active_flag = 'Y' 
AND    t2.active_flag = 'Y' 
AND    j.deleted_at IS NULL
GROUP 
BY     t.state_id
ORDER 
BY     t3.name
```

Comment: Read this: http://rpbouman.blogspot.de/2007/05/debunking-group-by-myths.html and this: http://www.mysqlperformanceblog.com/2006/09/06/wrong-group-by-makes-your-queries-fragile/ to understand what was wrong your MySQL query.

Comment: You can't run a group by on just one column. If you don't have an aggregate column , then you'll need to group by all columns in the output. Either way, you'd still have to group by all columns except for the aggregate column, so...You'd have to either modify the output,, or write another query.

Answer (score 1):

Your query uses a `group by` on one column. Different from some other platforms such as Sybase, Oracle requires all individual select elements to occur in the `group by` or be used in a group function such as `sum`, `max` and `avg`.
I consider this requirement a good thing; it makes the outcome of queries deterministic.
To port this query to Oracle, ensure for each select item you either:

- include it in the `group by` (nowadays that can be done using the alias or the full expression).
- or include it in a group function such as `max`.

If you need subtotals etc. please consider the use of analytical functions. They allow you to specify a different window for which something is calculated. Or use `grouping sets` and the likes. Good luck!

Comment: Thanks Guido. Finally ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY <column> ORDER BY <column>) AS <alias> solved my purpose.